# reset dropdown control to default value using javasccript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have div tag inside the div tag i have an drop down control which is binded to the database values
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
     --select--
        india
        us
        Auz

i have an checkbox control once i check then this the div tag will be visable uncheck the checkbox theen div tag will be invisable.

if the user select some value in the dropdown control like "AUZ" again if user checks or unchecks the checkbox  it should always show first value  "--select--"

hope  my Question is  clear

can any one give the syntax how to achieve, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please include code which you are trying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reset your dropdown, select its first option, and set the selected attribute to true.

```
$("#yourSelectId option:first").attr("selected", true);
```